# Database Connectivity in PHP - unexpected error

Tags: php, sql, connection, database-connection, connection-string

Following is my piece of code in which I am trying to create database connectivity. Please see the comments below in the code in which I mentioned where exactly the problem is occurring. Moreover, I also mentioned one connectivity code that is working fine.

Please let me know how I can call my `dbconfig.php` so it'll behave like that piece of code that results to successful connection.

Thanks

```
<?php

//Including Header file for the connectivity to the database
require_once('Connections/dbconfig.php');

  mysql_select_db($database_dbconfig, $dbconfig);
  // If I use the following line of code for connectivity then it works perfectly fine:
  //$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rare','root','');
  $dbh= $dbconfig;
  $q = 'select resident_id,u_first,u_last from z_events group by resident_id';
  /*
  The following error will occur when I try to make a connection from the header file:
  Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\Users\QAD\Downloads\CAR\index12 - Copy.php on line 200 
  */
  $user = $dbh->prepare($q);
  $user->execute();
?>
```

**dbconfig.php**

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_dbconfig = "localhost";
$database_dbconfig = "rare";
$username_dbconfig = "root";
$password_dbconfig = "";
$dbconfig = mysql_pconnect($hostname_dbconfig, $username_dbconfig, $password_dbconfig) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to mix PDO and `mysql_*`????

Comment: i didnot know about it cause i am working on someone else project

Comment: That's why we have [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing mysql_* functions with PDO functions - first connecting to your database using mysql_connect and then using prepare() to query your database.

You should move to PDO completely, replace this line:

```
$dbconfig = mysql_pconnect($hostname_dbconfig, $username_dbconfig, $password_dbconfig) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

With this one:

```
$dbconfig = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $database_dbconfig . ';host=127.0.0.1', $username_dbconfig, $password_dbconfig);
```

And put this in your other file:

```
<?php

//Including Header file for the conectivity to the database
require_once('Connections/dbconfig.php');

  $dbh = $dbconfig;
  $q = 'select resident_id,u_first,u_last from z_events group by resident_id';
  $user = $dbh->prepare($q);
  $user->execute();
?>
```

Comment: i used direct variable into my queries thanks for the help..... i didnot know about PDO because i am working on someone else project.

Answer (score 3):

**Try This**

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -1):

change your database selection into this

```
mysql_select_db($database_dbconfig);
```